# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions socket issue

Tags: sockets, port, listen

i have a dedicated hosting plan. i want to listen my port number 49154 and save data received on this port. but when i ping on this port they listen the port means connection established but they don't receive the data. my server firewall is also off for this error is

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

why this happen please tell me the solution of this

Comment: Ping doesn't access ports. 'They listen the port means connection established' doesn't make any sense. Which side gets the error: server or client? Please clarify your question.

Comment: ping means when i send request on server through browser using client code and client and server make a connection but not save data on server which the client send..

Comment: No it doesn't. Ping means executing the `ping` program. If you meant something else, you should have said so. What you are referring to is a connection test. You need to be clear about these things. You haven't answered my other question. Who gets this error? and what are they doing when they get it?

Comment: the error is on server side the error massage is  An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions